# idsIterator.remove() throws IllegalStateException

Tags: java, illegalstateexception, listiterator

I am trying to use the listIterator's `remove` method. However, I am getting an `IllegalStateException`

Here is my code:

```
private List<Category> findDescendantsOfCurrentCategory() {
    List<Category> categoryList = new ArrayList<>(mCategoryList);

    List<Category> descendantCategories = new ArrayList<>();

    Stack<String> categoriesIds = new Stack<>();
    categoriesIds.push(mCategoryId);

    ListIterator<Category> categoryListIterator = categoryList.listIterator();

    ListIterator<String> idsIterator = categoriesIds.listIterator();

    while (idsIterator.hasNext()) {
        String parentId = idsIterator.next();

        while (categoryListIterator.hasNext()) {
            Category category = categoryListIterator.next();

            if (category.getParentId().equals(parentId)) {
                idsIterator.add(category.getId());

                descendantCategories.add(category);
            }

            categoryListIterator.remove();
        }

        idsIterator.remove();
    }

    return descendantCategories;
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
03-09 23:11:33.160 25298-25298/com.example.clients.someoneplatform.dev E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.clients.someoneplatform.dev, PID: 25298
              java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.remove(AbstractList.java:67)
        at com.example.clients.someoneplatform.ui.categories.list.ListCategoriesFragment.findDescendantsOfCurrentCategory(ListCategoriesFragment.java:186)
        at com.example.clients.someoneplatform.ui.categories.list.ListCategoriesFragment.startAddEditCategoryForModification(ListCategoriesFragment.java:154)
        at com.example.clients.someoneplatform.ui.categories.list.ListCategoriesFragment.access$200(ListCategoriesFragment.java:39)
        at com.example.clients.someoneplatform.ui.categories.list.ListCategoriesFragment$1.onCategoryModifyButtonClicked(ListCategoriesFragment.java:124)
        at com.example.clients.someoneplatform.ui.categories.list.ListCategoriesAdapter$ViewHolder.onModifyButtonClicked(ListCategoriesAdapter.java:134)
        at com.example.clients.someoneplatform.ui.categories.list.ListCategoriesAdapter$ViewHolder_ViewBinding$2.doClick(ListCategoriesAdapter$ViewHolder_ViewBinding.java:47)
        at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21209)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Comment: what does the IlligaleStateException say?

Comment: @DZDomi nothing.

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Comment: @Kayaman posted...

Comment: @DZDomi see the stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#remove()) on ListIterator says about the remove method: "It can be made only if add(E) has not been called after the last call to next or previous."

So you basically have to rewrite your code that you don't use the add function before calling remove